# Angular - rxjs - Transform Observable array to another Observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

**Scenario :**

- Maybe it's something simple, but I can not find a solution.
- I have a service "firstService" that returns an Observable of A[].
  I have a service "secondService" that is passed an object A and returns an Observable .
  What I want at the end is an object B[].
- Object A is different from object B.

**Todo :**

- **I want to avoid double subscription.**

I have it programmed like this,
 Although I know it is **not correct due to the double subscription**:

```
this.B = [];
this.services.firstService().subscribe(
elements => {
   elements.forEach (element => {
     this.services.secondService(element).subscribe(s => {
       this.B.push(s);
     })
   });
});
```

Which operators or combination of operators would improve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscriptions inside subscriptions usually can be solved by using `operators`. What you are probably looking for is the `mergeMap` operator, which takes an emitted item from the so-called *outer observable* (in your case: `this.services.firstService()`) and maps it to a new *inner observable*, which in your case would be `this.services.secondService(element)`.

Now, in your specific case, each emission of the outer observable causes the creation of **multiple** inner observables, due to `elements` being a list. You have multiple options to deal with that, but I would suggest to use the `zip` operator. It transforms an `Observable<B>[]` to an `Observable<B[]>`, which is exactly what you want.

Your example can be solved like this:

```
import {zip, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.services.firstService().pipe(
    mergeMap(elements => 
       <Observable<B[]>> zip(...elements.map(element =>
            this.services.secondService(element)))
    ))
    .subscribe(elements => {
        this.B = elements;
});
```

More info on the used operators can be found here:

`zip` http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

`mergeMap` http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: Please see my edit, zip operator takes only spreaded arrays :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Applying your solution proposal I get the following error:
ERROR TS2345 Unable to assign an argument of type "(elements: A []) => OperatorFunction <B, {}>" to the type parameter "(value: A [], index: number) => ObservableInput <{}> "
   The type 'OperatorFunction <B, {}>' can not be assigned to the type 'ObservableInput <{}>'.
    The type 'OperatorFunction <B, {}>' can not be assigned to the type 'Iterable <{}>'.
       The property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in the type 'OperatorFunction <B, {}>'.
I've tried, but I can not figure out what happens.

Comment: This lookes like the return type of `zip` cannot be inferred. Could you try casting it to the desired type, I'll add it in an edit.

Comment: Oh, I forgot: Make sure to include the correct `zip`. Import it from "rxjs", not from "rxjs/operators"

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed a problem with the import. It is not necessary to do the cast. Solved!

Comment: how does the ... work? i think its called the spread operator? i read some documentation on it, but now sure what its doing in this example, or how its being used here, can some one explain, please